# C# Visual Studio Validate so text box only allows value between A-H

Tags: c#

I need help on allowing my textbox data entered to only be in the field between A-H and then displayed to a listbox. This is my code so far, thank you. I can still select letters outwith A-H, yet I get an error message no matter what letter I select. I need it so I can only select A-H and if I select anything outwith that it displays an error message.

```
try
{ 
    if (!this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('A') ||
        !this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('B') ||
        !this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('C') || 
        !this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('D') || 
        !this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('E') || 
        !this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('F') || 
        !this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('G') || 
        !this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('H'))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Correct your coach is valid!");
    }
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

LstFinalB.Items.Add(TxtCoach.Text);
```

Comment: Is something not working with your code?  If you aren't getting the desired outcome, please tell us the issue(s) you have and what you think it should be doing so that you can get some help.

Comment: Updated, sorry.

Comment: Your `if()` is true unless the textbox contains _all_ letters between A and H. Check your boolean logic. You also always add the text to the listbox.

Comment: Also, you always add the text because that happens *after* the try-catch (in other words, any error thrown does not prevent that part from being executed).

Comment: Use regular expression here to get the desired outcome. This should only allow characters `a - h` in upper and lower case. `^[a-hA-H]*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            try
            {
                if (this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('A') ||
                    this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('B') ||
                    this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('C') ||
                    this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('D') ||
                    this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('E') ||
                    this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('F') ||
                    this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('G') ||
                    this.TxtCoach.Text.Contains('H'))
                {
                    LstFinalB.Items.Add(TxtCoach.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Correct your coach is valid!");
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Your If statement logic was wrong and you would never have a correct input, and the Listbox.Items.Add(Item) was also in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to validate the data entered in the input box.

```
public bool IsAccepted(String textToValidate)
{
    Regex strPattern = new Regex("^[a-hA-H]*$");

    if (!strPattern.IsMatch(textToValidate))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of how I tested it via a Console app:

[image]